# Problem in equality of two functions.

Tags: functions

First of all, my book states that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal iff.:

- $Dom(f) = Dom(g)$
- $Codom(f) = Codom(g)$
- For each $x\in Dom(f)$ ,    $f(x) = g(x)$ and    vice-versa.

  which is fairly intuitive and self-explanatory.

But, I am not able to understand this:

Consider  $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ and $g(x)=x+2$. Let both of the domains be $\mathbb R$. However, if we take $x=2$ in $f(x)$, then the $f$ image of $2$ will be undefined. So, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R - {2}$. So, by the first bullet point, $f\neq g$.

But, by basic algebra:  $x+2=\dfrac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x-2)}=\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}$
Now, my first question is :

> Can we use algebra to translate a function into another form, just
> like I did here?

If the answer to the above question is yes, then we clearly get $Dom(f)=Dom(g)$, and so $f=g$.

Another doubt:$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\dfrac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}=x+2$
Now, I have two versions of $f(x)$. But, if I put $x=2$ in either of the versions, I get different results. So, what is the problem?

Comment: In both of the versions, have u assumed that $x-2\ne 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that you can alter the function is if and only if the domain allows it.
For example in our case.
  $f:\mathbb{R}-{2}->\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x-2)}=\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ then you can use algebra to transform the function into $g(x)=x+2$
These functions are unequal in general because $Dom(f)\neq Dom(g)$, but equal in the subset $\mathbb{R}-{2}\subset\mathbb{R}$